# Вызвать предупреждение в C#

Tags: c#, .net, warning

У меня есть функция, которая может работать, даже если получила некорректные данные. Но я хочу предупредить пользователя/программиста, что он ввел не то что нужно, не выбрасывая исключение и не прерывая работу программы. Можно ли как-то вывести сообщение во время выполнения программы в режиме дебага в error list окно или еще куда?

Comment: `Debug.Assert();`

Comment: А почему вам не подходит throw?

Comment: Console.Error()

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но меня смущает что функция должна иметь несколько областей ответственности: собственно логика в нее заложенная и оповещение пользователя. Думаю, лучше ее разделить на 2, одна из которых будет только и заниматься проверкой и выдавать, например, результат: параметр корректный, параметр некорректный, параметр в "зоне риска"

Comment: @Bulson этот способ к сожалению полностью игнорируется vs при использовании функции из скомпилированной сборки.

Comment: @SkiF нельзя вызывать исключение, так как это не ошибка, и обрабатывать ее не требуется. Но нужно предупредить программиста/записать в лог/вывести сообщение, что поведение будет не тем, какое ожидалось изначально и возможно именно в этом случае часть работы функции необходимо выполнить самостоятельно

Comment: @Sublihim функция находится в библиотеке и будет использоваться не в консольных приложениях

Comment: Многопоточность

Comment: Что вы называете предупреждением? Как именно вы предупреждение видете? Может вы имеете ввиду MessageBox? Может сообщение в трее? Может сообщение в системном журнале? Может сообщение в журнале браузера? Может логирование в файл? Уточните конкретнее.

Comment: @mirypoko а вы где-то описали это в вопросе?

Comment: @nick_n_a мне нужно, чтобы программист во время проверки работы программы увидел, что функция из подключенной библиотеки предупреждает его о том, что ее поведение немного измениться например из-за того, что вместо int был получен long (часть работы не будет выполнена). Желательно чтобы, например логеры asp.net приложения такое событие логировали. Но они логируют исключения, а например Debug.Assert игнорируют

Comment: Что такое "Логер asp.net" ? Или имеется ввиду консоль студии? Может это всётаки журнал событий?

Comment: @nick_n_a консоль студии подойдет, жарнал событий подойдет. Мне нужно чтобы программист мог понять, почему у него изменилось поведение функции.

Comment: Если вам не подходит `Debug` используйте `Trace` у него все те же методы, что и у `Debug`, но он работает в development, его можно настроить писать в текстовой файл, или в системный журнал.

Comment: @Bulson Trace.TraceWarning то что нужно, выводит сообщение в Output.

Comment: @Bulson оформите, пожалуйста, ваш комментарий в ответ, чтобы я его выбрал.

Comment: У вас есть преимущество, у меня только теоретические познания, а у вас уже есть опыт практического применения. Так что опишите, пожалуйста, свой опыт практического использования в качестве ответа и просигнализируйте мне, а я вам плюс поставлю.

Answer (score 1):

Существуют библиотеки логирования, которые позволяют настраивать место назначения логов (консоль, текстовые файлы, СУБД, сетевой сокет), включать/выключать логи, и многое другое. При этом они позволяют выполнять все эти настройки в разрезе отдельных классов и прочих условий.

Для .NET рекомендую посмотреть в сторону [NLOG](http://nlog-project.org/)